# swift выдает значения nil

Tags: json, swift, swift3

3 день не могу понять в чем проблема вроде бы код правильный вроде бы все парсится правильно но все же выдает ошибку вот код

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource  {

    @IBOutlet weak var NameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var LogoPicture: UIImageView!

    let urlString = "https//my/ip.com"

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var nameArray = [String]()
    var timeArray = [NSNumber]()
    var logoArray = [String]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let name = defaults.string(forKey: "NameText"){
        NameLabel.text = name
        }
        if let logo = defaults.string(forKey: "LogoText"){
            let strurl = NSURL(string: logo)
            let dtinternet = NSData(contentsOf:strurl! as URL)
            LogoPicture.image = UIImage(data: dtinternet as! Data)
            self.view.addSubview(LogoPicture)}

        self.downloadJsonWithURL() 
    }

    @IBAction func ExitButton(_ sender: Any) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
    }

    func downloadJsonWithURL(){
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
                as? NSDictionary {
                //print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "data"))

                if let dataArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "data") as? NSArray {
                    for datata in dataArray {
                        if let dataDict = datata as?  NSDictionary {

                            if let created = dataDict.value(forKey: "created") {
                                self.timeArray.append(created as! NSNumber)
                            }


                            if let authorArray = dataArray.value(forKey: "author") as? NSArray {
                                for datata1 in authorArray {
                                    if let authorDict = datata1 as?  NSDictionary {
                                        if let namea = authorDict.value(forKey: "name") {
                                             self.nameArray.append(namea as! String)
                                        }
                                        if let logo = authorDict.value(forKey: "logo") {
                                            self.logoArray.append(logo as! String)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            //print(self.nameArray)

                            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({self.tableView.reloadData()})
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }).resume()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return nameArray.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.nameView.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]

        let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timeArray[indexPath.row]))
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") //Set timezone that you want
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        cell.timeView.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)
        print(timeArray[indexPath.row])

        let imgURL = NSURL(string: logoArray[indexPath.row])
        if imgURL != nil {
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: imgURL as! URL)
        cell.logoView.image = UIImage(data: data as! Data)
        }
        return cell
    }

}
```

вот ошибка `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

вот в этой строке `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell` . подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю неверно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проверь приходят ли данные если да то проверь связки в TableViewCell

Comment: данный приходили ошибка была return nameArray.count , неправильно выбрал элемент для этой строки нужно было timeArray так как nameArray давало неправильное число